# Creating routes with an optional path prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

How can I go about making my routes recognise an optional prefix parameter as follows:

```
/*lang/controller/id
```

In that the lang part is optional, and has a default value if it's not specified in the URL:

```
/en/posts/1   => lang = en
/fr/posts/1   => lang = fr
/posts/1      => lang = en
```

*EDIT*

Ideally, I'm looking to do this across many controllers and actions by mapping a namespace:

```
map.namespace "*lang" do |lang|
  lang.resources :posts
  lang.resources :stories
end
```

Comment: In your example you only reference 1 controller, but I take it you want to create this route for every controller?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, I've managed to sort out this problem:

THere is no way of doing this in Rails by default (at least, not yet). Instead of using namespaces and default values, I needed to install [Sven Fuchs' routing filter](http://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter/tree/master).

Once the plugin is installed, I added the following file to my lib directory:

```
require 'routing_filter/base'

module RoutingFilter
  class Locale < Base

    # remove the locale from the beginning of the path, pass the path
    # to the given block and set it to the resulting params hash
    def around_recognize(path, env, &block)
      locale = nil
      path.sub! %r(^/([a-zA-Z]{2})(?=/|$)) do locale = $1; '' end
      returning yield do |params|
        params[:locale] = locale || 'en'
      end
    end

    def around_generate(*args, &block)
      locale = args.extract_options!.delete(:locale) || 'en'
      returning yield do |result|
        if locale != 'en'
          result.sub!(%r(^(http.?://[^/]*)?(.*))){ "#{$1}/#{locale}#{$2}" }
        end 
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I added this line to routes.rb:

```
map.filter 'locale'
```

This basically fills out a before and after hook, generated by the plugin, that wraps the rails routing.

When a url is recognised, and before Rails gets to do anything with it, the around_recognize method is called. This will extract a two-letter code representing the locale, and pass it through in the params, defaulting to 'en' if no locale is specified.

Likewise, when a url is generated, the locale parameter will be pushed into the URL on the left side.

This gives me the following urls and mappings:

```
/   => :locale => 'en'
/en => :locale => 'en'
/fr => :locale => 'fr'
```

All existing url helpers work as before, with the only difference being that unless the locale is specified, it is preserved:

```
home_path                  => /
home_path(:locale => 'en') => /
home_path(:locale => 'fr') => /fr
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this worked great for some translation/localization/internationalization work I'm doing. FYI, you don't have to add that file to your library -- the 'locale' filter is already included in the plugin.  All you should have to do is:

1. Install the plugin.
2. Add `map.filter 'locale'` to your routes.rb.
After that it just starts working!  Nice.  

I also added `RoutingFilter::Locale.include_default_locale = false` to my environment.rb to avoid `/en` being in my links.

Works great, I hope Sven's plugin gets pulled into the Rails I18n codebase.

Comment: Here's another option I ran across today, haven't looked into it (routing-filter is working great) but might be of interest to others:  http://github.com/raul/translate_routes

Comment: Any ideas on how to translate this into Rails3?

Answer (score 2):

You can define defaults in a route using the `:defaults` key. Try this:

```
map.connect ':lang/posts/:id', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show',
                               :defaults => { :lang => 'en' }
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 2.1.1 on my machine. http://localhost:3000/posts/1 gives No route matches "/posts/1" with {:method=>:get}
Looks like :defaults only provides parameters not in the route? I need to investigate: I didn't know about :defaults at all, so thanks!

Comment: I think this is on the right track - is it possible to integrate this option with namespaces and resources?

Comment: IIRC, defaults work like default values in method parameters -- i.e. defaults can only be used on the last values when listed in order, not the first values

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this old question, but it may be useful.

```
  map.with_options(:path_prefix => ":locale") do |m|
    m.resources :posts
    m.resources :stories        
  end
```

And you have to add before filter to application controller to define locale, such as

```
before_filter :define_locale

def define_locale
  if params[:locale] == nil
    I18n.locale = 'en'
  else
    I18n.locale = params[:locale]
  end
end
```

Comment: The path prefix is not optional, so you always have to supply a locale unless you duplicate the routes outside the block.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (no time to test right now) that this might work:

```
map.connect ':language/posts/:id', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show'
map.connect 'posts/:id', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show'
```

OK, tried it - it works, on Rails 2.1.1 at least. So that's good. Can't get the :defaults idea to work, though, which is a shame, because it's DRYer.

Answer (score 1):

Thought you could at one time use a [key] => nil to specify an optional parameter.  Something like:

```
map.connect ':lang/posts/:id', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show', :lang => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer Rails (3 and above) you can do this with optional path segments:

### Step 1:

```rb
scope path: '(:lang)', constraints: { lang: /|de|en/ } do
  resources :posts
end
```

The parentheses make the `:lang` segment optional, the constraints limit it to either `de`, `en` or an empty string.

### Step 2:

In your controller you can then read that segment from the params hash:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  around_action :set_locale

  def set_locale(&action)
    locale = params[:lang] || I18n.default_locale # or your custom rules
    I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
  end

end
```

### Step 3:

There is a slight problem when you perform a redirect: The `:lang` segment gets lost. To fix this override `default_url_options`:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def default_url_options
    super.merge(lang: params[:lang])
  end

end
```

### Other aspects::

**Mailers:**

If your mailers generate links and you want your `:lang` prefix there, too, you can add a `default_url_options` to your `ApplicationMailer` class and read `:lang` from elsewhere, e.g. from a user record (if any) or from a parameter

**Route defaults:**

If you want all generated paths/urls to add the `:lang` segment as soon as possible, you can add a default to the route

```rb
scope path: '(:lang)', constraints: { lang: /|de|en/ }, defaults: { lang: 'de' } do
  # Your normal routes
end
```

... but IMHO that would more or less defeat the purpose of this whole concept, because any generated path/url would then get a `:lang` prefix regardles of the incoming route.

I found it more practical to handle all defaults in the controller and treat routes without the `:lang` prefix as a primary route and not just as a subordinate alias. On the other hand, that might be exactly what you want...

**Routes without a prefix:**

There is a small caveat: When you set up your routes like above and then redirect to a route which doesn't have the `:lang` path segment, that value ends up in the query parameters:

```rb
scope path: '(:lang)', constraints: { lang: /|de|en/ } } do
  resources :posts
end

resource :home
```

Redirecting from a route like `/de/posts/1` to the home route would result in an URL like this:

```
/home?lang=de
```

... because the router has no path segment to put the `lang` param into. On the plus side, if you redirect back to a posts route, the user would get the original incoming route prefix.

**Update:** Rails 7.1 has a solution for this problem: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43770