# Optional path prefix persistence, using Sven Fuchs' routing filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made my routes recognize optional path prefixes, but now I want route generation to remember them without me specifying them each time. I'm using the solution presented here:

[Creating routes with an optional path prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212425/creating-routes-with-an-optional-path-prefix)

Here are some examples:

Let's say I'm here: `{ path => "/", :contoller => 'welcome', :action => 'index', :locale => 'en' }` then route generation works like this:

```
events_path #=> "/en/events"
event_path(1) #=> "/en/events/1"
```

This is exactly what I want, and everything's great.

Now let's consider I'm here:  `{ path => "/fr", :contoller => 'welcome', :action => 'index', :locale => 'fr' }` then route generation works like this:

```
events_path #=> "/en/events"
events_path(1) #=> "/en/events/1"
```

This is not helping me at all. What it would be natural to have is `events_path` to remember `params[:locale]` and generate `"/fr/events"`. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying the desired behaviour is exactly the one I've written routing_filter for :)

Try using the provided locale filter by installing the plugin and simply adding map.filter(:locale) to your routes.

If that does not help, please email me or send me a message on github.