# Optional part in rails routing path

Tags: rails-routing

I am trying to create a route for a page which can have `param1` and `param2`. `Param2` is optional part and the code will take a default value if the value is not present. The following is what I am trying to do

```
match '/school/:dept/:staff/show' => staff#show
match '/school/:staff/show' => staff#show
```

I have a bunch of statements like the above which seems to be too much of repetition. Is there a better way to do this. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212425/creating-routes-with-an-optional-path-prefix) has an approach using a third party option. Considering it is an older post, looking to see if this is currently supported with rails.

Answer (score 0):

As per: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3

> We can do this by defining a route like this, directing any matching route to our info#about action. Note that we can nest parentheses when creating optional parameters.

```
    match "/:year(/:month(/:day))" => "info#about"
```